# How to make my handle method polymorphic when using traits

Tags: scala

I want my handle method to be able to take any Animal type and then be able to actually have the specific type so I can continue processing.

I just sketched out what I am looking for:

```
sealed trait Animal
case class Dog(id: Int) extends Animal
case class Cat(id: Int) extends Animal
case class Owl(id: Int) extends Animal



object AnimalHandler {
  def handle(animal: Animal) = animal match {

    case Dog => processDog(dog)
    case Cat => processCat(cat)

  } 
}
```

How can I design my domain to work like the above?

Answer (score 2):

The code you have pretty much works as-is.

The syntax on the pattern match would need to include a variable name, and if you're actually using the attributes of the case classes you would probably use the pattern to extract them.

```
sealed trait Animal
case class Dog(id: Int) extends Animal
case class Cat(id: Int) extends Animal
case class Owl(id: Int) extends Animal

def processDog(dog: Dog) = println(s"woof ${dog.id}")
def processCat(id: Int) = println(s"meow $id")
def processOwl(owl: Owl, id: Int) = println(s"hoot ${owl.id}")

object AnimalHandler {
  def handle(animal: Animal) = {
    case dog: Dog => processDog(dog)
    case Cat(id) => processCat(id)
    case owl @ Owl(id) => processOwl(owl, id)
  }
}
```

Some notes:

- given a sealed trait, the compiler will warn you if your pattern match isn't complete (in your case you were missing handling for Owl).
- if the body of a method/function is nothing but a pattern match on the argument you can skip the `animal match`

Comment: In Java, this would work but you would have to explicitly cast in the case statement right to get the actual type?

Comment: Switch/Case statements in Java are much more limited. The `x: Type` syntax is saying "this pattern consists of a single value of type Type, which I want to refer to as x". Alternatively you could have something like `Dog(id)` as your pattern where you would get a value named id, with the dog's id, if you were passed a dog.

Comment: I've added some more examples of the ways in which pattern matching can be used to extract values, HTH